# Which word to describe the sound of broken-up small ice shards in water?

Tags: onomatopoeia

I am trying to find the best word to describe the sound that a mass of small ice shards collected at the edges of a lake and moving in the waves make, after the ice has broken up? The sound is soft and continuos but still sharp and crystalline, and "rattling", "crackling" etc just doesn´t seem to describe it very well. Is there a good word for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Sound after the ice has broken up? Where does this sound come from?

Comment: Does the sound resemble the *swish* of a broom? Or *rustle* of leaves, perhaps? (going by the stated fact that there's such a sound at all.)

Comment: @user405662 The sound is caused by the "rattling together" of the small ice shards because they are moving in the waves. There certainly is such a sound, I hear it most winters in the lake close to my home :) Swishing or rustling is similar, and I thank you for the suggestion, but they do not really describe the "crystalline" nature of the sound.

Comment: There isn't always a  single word for everything. That's why poetry was invented.

Comment: Are we looking for an unknown word of undefined syllables that is soft, continuous, yet sharp but not crackling?

Comment: @John Lawler Well, yes, your are right :) In the absence of a single good word I guess "rustling sharply" might be the best descrition.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin Yes, that is a good description, if there is such a word.

Comment: 'Tinkling sound'?

Comment: As usual, too subtle. I was teasing.

Comment: Can you make a fill-in-the-blank sentence?

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat For example like this: "When the ice on the lake breaks up, small shards amasses and ___ at the shoreline". But as John Lawler said, there probably isn´t a single word for this so maybe "rustles sharply" or "rustles softly" will have to be used to describe it as closely as possible.